# When the dg cluster category of a quiver is saturated?

Tags: differential-graded-algebras, quivers, cluster-algebras

Let $Q$ be a finite quiver without oriented cycles. In https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1960 , Keller defines the dg cluster category $C_Q$ of $Q$.
When is $C_Q$ smooth proper dg-category?
If $Q$ is a Dynkin quiver, then $C_Q$ might be smooth proper.